# question about gifts given, can someone legally take back a gift?

Tags: small-claims-court, gift, return

A "friend" of mine is currently trying to get back an item from me they gifted, they claim it was given because of mania and I took advantage because I did not decline the gift. I have photo proof they were excited for the gift to get to my house etc and there was no signs they were being forced by me to send it, is there anything they can do? they claim they're going to get the cops and small claim court involved, is this possible?

Comment: If someone gifts you something, it's yours entirely. It is similar to them not having owned it in the first place. Don't see how they could take any legal action whatsoever afaik. I am saying this because I did have a somewhat of a similar situation before but in regards to something really expensive and an actual legal property, and that's what my lawyer advised. Of course, this applies to the country I live in (Pakistan), but I would assume the case would be much similar elsewhere.

Comment: IIRC there are some very limited cases where this is possible in Switzerland. Like if you bought a very expensive ring for your fiancée and later drop her. I'll need to search the relevant law, though.

Comment: You have to specifiy the jurisdiction. Such things do vary from country to country. The term "small claims court" may be a cluse where you are, but not enough.

Comment: Unfortunately, the duplicate makes no note of the actual question here: is a gift valid, if one party was not able to legally enter into a contract due to their state of mind. At least that is what they claim.